# Issue running openx on windows 2008 R2 with IIS, PHP 5.4.5.0, and MySQL

Tags: php, iis, openx

I am trying to setup openx on Windows 2008 R2 with IIS, PHP 5.4.5.0, and MySQL. I have IIS setup and working, php setup and working (phpinfo(); works), and I have MySQL setup and working.

However when I try to hit 
    http://www.myserver.com/www/delivery/avw.php?what=bannerid:1411

I get the following returned: 
    GIF89a€ÿÿÿ!ù,D;

I want to say that I've seen something like this in the past and it was because I needed a PHP extension enabled. I thought it was GD2 so I enabled that in the php.ini: extension=php_gd2.dll. However that doesn't seem to have helped.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions why I'd be seeing this?

Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in OpenX when run on PHP 5.4. Until OpenX fixes these bugs (and they haven't as of 2.8.10), you'll want to apply the fixes mentioned in http://www.teslina.com/en/tutorials/openx/fehlermeldungen-problemlosungen/.

Namely the problem is that there is header information sent to the browser before the image is rendered, and because of that you're seeing garbage.

Comment: The fixes work only for statistics page from user account, not from administrator account :-(